# Await inside nodejs snowflake stream.on('data', fn)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to process the data stream and insert it in DB synchronously. How can do it. If I pass an async function to *stream.on* it won't be processed synchronously.

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    logger.info("Initiating snowflake connection")
    const connection = await getConnection();
    const statement = await connection.execute({
        sqlText: 'SELECT * FROM CMO_DATA;',
        complete: function (err, stmt, rows) {
            var stream = statement.streamRows();
            stream.on('data', async function (row) {
                logger.info("Processing data =>", row)
                await SnowflakeData.insertOne(row);
                count++;
            });
            stream.on('end', function () {
                logger.info('All rows consumed =>', count);
                resolve()
            });
            stream.on('error', function (err) {
                logger.error('Failed to consume all rows', err);
                reject(err)
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Use `for await (const row of stream) await SnowflakeData.insertOne(row);`. But really, why use `insertOne`? Isn't there a multi-value insert?

Comment: Handle all rows in `end` event.

Comment: The amount of data is expected to be huge and that's the reason why i want to handle it whenever a chunk is recieved

Comment: Either go for @Bergi's suggestion or refactor the call to `SnowflakeData.insertOne()` into a `stream.Writable.writev()` to support multi-row inserts